# Are LDS missionaries taught languages to a level of fluency in under three months which takes other schools years?

Tags: language, christianity, lds

In [*How do Mormon missionaries learn foreign languages so quickly?*](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/26468/6071) it is claimed that LDS (Mormon) missionaries spend only up to ten weeks in languge learning, and that most are "fluent" within one year. These missionaries receive this training together at the Missionary Training Centre, Utah, which means they will be studying many languages together, outside of a speech community for those languages. By comparison, most Protestant missionaries spend 2-3 years in language learning, and if possible this time is spent in a society where the language they're learning is spoken regularly.

An [NPR story](http://www.npr.org/2014/06/07/319805068/lessons-from-the-language-boot-camp-for-mormon-missionaries) claims that the LDS school is recognised as one of the best language instruction school in the world. It quotes one student who says that 5 weeks at their school gets you to where you would be in three years at a university, and that nine weeks at the LDS school is equivalent to 64 weeks at a US army school.

It says that their teaching strategy is focused on contextual learning rather than memorization, which is definitely how many experts say language should be taught. But the time spent at the school sounds incredibly short. Is there any independent evidence that the students of the Missionary Training Centre actually become fluent to the level that the students of other missionary, government or commercial schools take a couple of years to reach?

Comment: I was recently reading *Fluent Forever* by Gabriel Wyner, and he states that the key technique the Mormons use is doing pronunciation first. Before they move to grammar or vocabulary, they drill to be able to recognize and produce the phonemes.

Comment: I went to the MTC (Missionary Training Center) in Provo Utah. My favourite joke is, "What's the difference between the MTC and a maximum security prison?" A: *Prisoners get visitors*. Your first day in the MTC feels like 3, your first week like a month, those who learn foreign languages say they feel like they've been there a year after their 6 weeks of training.

Comment: I went to MTC as well, and I would say the reason for getting fluid quickly is because after those few weeks, the missionaries get thrown out into the mission field and start to actually talk to people. After a few weeks out you start to understand the people you talk to ;-) And yes, it would be pretty impossible to have more intense language training than at MTC, imho. But I wonder what an answer would have to look like?

Comment: @kutschkem How would having your education outside a speech community and then stopping formal language education once you're in the speech community produce more fluency than having formal education within a speech community for a longer period of time? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @curiousdannii You're right, I was just assuming a fixed length of learning of a few weeks here. I'm also just saying that MTC is intense. Just ignore me, I don't have much to add to the question ;-)

Comment: @kutschkem Oh I think yours (and others) personal experience is important and valuable, even if it isn't enough for an answer on this site. I don't doubt that MTC is giving you a good training, but I'm skeptical that it can be as good as a longer time of language learning.

Comment: Speaking from total ignorance but interested curiosity, might it not be that they are being specifically trained for one purpose, for which a spectacularly limited vocabulary would suffice?

Comment: @benjol That could be the case, but then I don't think claiming fluency would be appropriate.

Comment: Learning a new language is intensely expedited through immersion.  Years in a classroom can produce semi-fluency, but nowhere near as well as experiencing it firsthand, with actual speakers.

Comment: We were encouraged to NOT speak English except for emergencies and within the context of learning (such as what is the Japanese word for xxx?), 24x7. This had my brain working overtime and even brought to memory long forgotten German and Spanish from High School and Jr. High, and I believe that this was a key factor in speeding up the learning process. Fluency really is a subjective term and some languages are much easier than others. After a year in Japan, I was once mistaken for a native speaker over the phone, but there are *very* few foreigners who speak Japanese "fluently".

Comment: @James So your classes were immersion? How many native speakers were there during that time?

Comment: @curiousdannii: Classes were as immersive as possible (obviously there had to be much more English the first couple of weeks). I didn't have any native teachers, but all three had just returned from 2 years there. In the 8 weeks I was in the MTC, native teachers probably wouldn't have helped much. We focused mostly on grammar and vocabulary, and a little on pronounciation.  I had some difficulty understanding natives for the first couple of months in Japan, but I had the foundational grammar and vocabulary I needed. It did help a lot that I spent 24/7 with natives for months 2-10 in Japan.

Comment: @James Sounds like a woman my mother knew in college--she specifically asked for a roommate of Spanish origin and then asked the roommate to only speak Spanish to her unless it was an emergency.

Comment: Another reason may well be that they select their trainees for their aptitude at learning languages?

Comment: @jwenting Nope. LDS missionaries are chosen primarily by moral worthiness, and at least in theory are volunteers. There is social pressure to be a missionary in many LDS congregations, which does lead to some missionaries who don't want to be there, but to my knowledge the majority are sincere volunteers. Language learning aptitude isn't a strong deciding factor. As anecdotal evidence; I studied Japanese for 2 years in high school and was largely unsuccessful. I was assigned to a Spanish-speaking mission and became acceptably fluent within my first year.

Comment: @Benjol My experience agrees at least in part with the idea that vocabulary for LDS missionaries learning a language is specialized and thus narrower than it would be in other language learning programs. If we define "fluent" as `able to express oneself easily and articulately`, I would argue that I was fluent in Spanish within my first year, with the caveat that I was not fluent in subjects outside of everyday living and religion.

Comment: A information post by a Mormon missionary on Mandarin learning in MTC is discussed here-http://www.chinese-forums.com/index.php?/topic/45603-language-learning-and-mandarin-mormon-missionaries/

Answer (score 3):

Languages have been divided from Group I to Group IV based on their complexity of learning by [students](http://www.languagetesting.com/how-long-does-it-take) through ACTFL Oral Proficiency Interview (OPI) Ratings. It takes about 16 weeks (480 hours) to reach a minimal aptitude of intermediate High while using the training offered by LTI for Group I languages.

Referring to Richard O [Cowan](http://eom.byu.edu/index.php/Missionary_Training_Centers) on the Missionary Training [Center](http://www.mormonnewsroom.org.au/article/preparation-with-purpose--life-in-a-mormon-missionary-training-center) Regimen which is based on a program which equals to 432 hours (9 hours each day for a total of 8 weeks which calculates to 432 excluding Sundays) developed by the U.S. Army. The hours can also increase from a minimum of 9 hours to a maximum of 12 hours of language/religious learning per day.

Also distractions such as phoning home, chatting with friends on the internet, watching TV or non-LDS videos, reading novels or newspapers, listening to popular music is banned in the language boot camp.

> The schedule is rigorous. Classes have ten to twelve students who meet in three-hour sessions, morning, afternoon, and evening. Studies include the scriptures, languages, and missionary methodology. Academic responsibilities are balanced by spiritual development and recreational opportunities. Temple attendance and weekly devotional addresses given by visiting General Authorities aid spiritual well-being. Exercise programs promote physical fitness.
>
> Trainees learn by listening and repeating. Classroom instructors are usually experienced former missionaries and foreign students from nearby campuses. Linguistic drills are related to the culture, customs, and characteristics of the assigned mission field. In one week basic grammar is learned, and after two weeks a missionary begins to converse, pray, and sing in a new language. In eight weeks, missionaries are reasonably adept in conversation and can teach gospel lessons in a foreign language.

Jonathan Green in his [blog](http://timesandseasons.org/index.php/2012/12/missions-and-language-learning/) states

> A foreign mission is a 16- or 22-month immersion experience coupled with strong motivation to learn the target language. (And for less than $10,000, it’s a fantastic bargain. If you shopped around carefully, you might find a 12-week study abroad program for the same price.) Missionaries also come into regular contact with a much broader spectrum of the foreign culture than most students studying abroad. With that amount of time, that degree of motivation, and that much interaction with native speakers, Mormon missionaries have an opportunity unavailable to most American college students. Despite their extensive experience, most returned missionaries still have gaps in their language skills and cultural knowledge. Missions are excellent preparation, but turning a mission language into a professionally useful language will take a bit more work.

**Research on Returned Missionary proficiency in Second Language**

**Research shows that foreign missions in a range of 16 to 22 months along with strong motivation to learn the target language and interaction/regular contact with native speakers tend to help the LDS missionaries to build their language skills to higher proficient levels equivalent to [K-12](http://www.k12.wa.us/worldlanguages/Standards/default.aspx) language teaching levels.**

Referring to the [book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=uouWcShtTBoC&pg=PA48&lpg=PA48&dq=Second+Language+Acquisition+Abroad&source=bl&ots=X9hIiA4m1a&sig=yfXZ6pmuONRQHwG0oqX8VIw7enc&hl=en&sa=X#v=onepage&q=Second%20Language%20Acquisition%20Abroad&f=false) 'Second Language Acquisition Abroad: The LDS Missionary Experience' edited by Lynne Hansen in 2012 which is an analysis of Latter Day Saints Returned Missionary (RM) second language acquisition skills, the following points have been summarized from the review of Robert Arthur [Cote](http://linguistlist.org/pubs/reviews/get-review.cfm?SubID=4557089).

1. The Church of the Latter Day Saints or the Mormon Church have created Missionary [Training](https://www.lds.org/new-era/1971/03/a-day-in-the-life-of-a-language-training-missionary?lang=eng) Centers (MTC) which are basically target language boot camps which utilize a hybrid task-based and focus-on-form approach to assist missionaries in both obtaining survival communication skills and acquiring the ability to spread religious [messages](https://www.lds.org/ensign/1982/10/become-acquainted-with-languages-tongues-and-people?lang=eng).

> This is accomplished by attending an eight-to-twelve week pre-departure immersion program at one of sixteen centers around the globe called Missionary Training Centers (MTC) in which the missionary receives six hours of language instruction per day five days a week. The focus at the MTC is on oral communication for survival and sharing religious views.
>
> After completing the language course, the missionaries are sent to their host country, where they are matched up with a companion who is either a native speaker of the target language. The pair remains together 24/7 for language study.

2. All interviews for the research mentioned below were conducted by telephone by ACTFL-certified testers and all tests were double or triple rated (triple if double ratings did not exactly agree).  Research indicated there are no significant differences in ratings between telephonic and face-to-face interview scores.

Research results through American Council on The Teaching of Foreign Languages (ACTFL) oral proficiency interview (OPI) shows that **the length of time immersed in a target language is better than only learning language in a classroom, but factors such as aptitude, motivation, amount and types of practice and nature of social interactions also play important roles and for optimal outcomes, additional instruction and negative feedback may be necessary.** The proficiency levels listed in the research are the minimum levels established by the various professions, and higher levels would often be preferred.

The missionaries tested had all spent about the same amount of  time in the language environment but did not all attain the same amount of proficiency. However, there are clear limits to their “missionary language” that might prevent them from participating in more linguistically demanding careers such as contract negotiation or professional translation.

> Nearly [all](http://679rnon-trad.wikispaces.com/file/view/RM+Lang+Dewey_Clifford_Nov3_09.doc) would meet the minimal proficiency requirements for K-12 language teaching, and a large percentage would be capable of using their language in service professions such as police and paramedics, customer service, social work, or billing and clerical work. It is clear from the data that **by the end of their missionary service, RMs are able to fluently discuss a variety of concrete and personal topics with others in their target language.  Their speaking proficiency levels are higher than those achieved by the typical undergraduate major.**

3. Much of the Returned Missionary target language was centered on teaching about religion, and this was done by memorizing chunks of language which were repeated over and over, creating a positive bias towards the ability to discuss religion.

> Many of the RMs showed their highest levels of target language ability when discussing religious matters, an ''ability pattern that OPI testers would describe as a hothouse special'', a skill rarely found in traditional students.

4. The strongest predictor of vocabulary attainment for the learners was time on the mission and out of the affective variables among motivation, attitude and faith, motivation was the strongest predictor.
5. The more time that passed and the less exposure to the target languages in the person's native land, the more vocabulary that was lost.
6. The larger the vocabulary of the language (lexicon), the greater the apparent savings benefit in relearning old words, and the better able one is to learn new words.
7. Researchers found during the measurement of oral fluency in mission languages that the pause variables have a stronger relationship to second language attainment, and the silent pauses, both in frequency and length, correlate most strongly with measures of language proficiency.

> Researchers determined that the pause variables have a stronger
> relationship to second language attainment, and ''the silent pauses, both in
> frequency and length, correlate most strongly with measures of language
> proficiency''.

Research in [2014](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/jbp/sic/2014/00000011/00000001/art00001?crawler=true) by Rachel W Kirk on Spanish proficiency of Mormon returned missionaries through written survey completed by 103 students shows many attained a high level of linguistic proficiency but their awareness of cultural issues and ability to articulate them were limited.

A research paper by Lynne [Hansen](http://www.huichawaii.org/assets/hansen,-lynne---the-lds-missionary-experience.pdf) also shows that European languages are learned faster by the English-speaking learners than are the more distant Asian languages and European languages are retained better than Asian languages.

Another study in [2013](http://www.consortiacademia.org/index.php/ijrsll/article/viewFile/561/278) among LDS learners found that two motivational factors, learners' interest in culture, travel, and people, and positive learning attitudes/experience and intended efforts predicted learners' interest in continuing foreign language learning.

> In other words, when the learners had positive attitudes towards L2 community, enjoyed the learning environment they were in, and made efforts to learn L2, the tendency that the learners desired to continue language study was high. This finding is similar to the results found in Wen's (2011) study which showed that positive learning attitudes/experience and intended efforts is a strong predictor for future L2 study.

Comment: This doesn't provide a comparison with other language schools.

Comment: @curiousdannii-Comparison between undergraduate majors and those of LDS returned missionaries in speaking proficiency levels show that LDS returned missionary speaking proficiency levels are higher than those achieved by the typical undergraduate major students.

Comment: That isn't the claim the question asks about.

Comment: The question asks about independent evidence about the students of the Missionary Training Centre actually becoming fluent to the level of students of other government or commercial schools. The answer talks about the existing research on returned missionary second language proficiency which is after a time interval between 16 to 22 months of foreign mission.

Comment: LDS (Mormon) missionaries spend up to 8 to 12 weeks in language learning in Missionary Training Centers which are target language boot camps. After completing the language course, the missionaries are sent to their host country where they are matched up with a companion who is a native speaker of the target language. The pair remains together 24/7 for language study.

Comment: These foreign missions in a range of 16 to 22 months along with strong motivation to learn the target language and interaction/regular contact with native speakers tend to help the LDS missionaries to build their language skills to higher proficient levels than that of undergraduate major students.

Comment: The claim made was that they were more fluent after their short time at MTC. I have absolutely no doubt that they become very proficient after being embedded in their mission culture for 2 years, but that's not what the question is asking, sorry.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30938/discussion-between-pericles316-and-curiousdannii).

Comment: This answer reflects a generalization that I do not doubt, but the results vary significantly from one language to another. After 8 weeks training in the Provo MTC for to serve in Finland (at the time considered the 2nd hardest language to learn next to Navajo, which at the time had no written component) my fellow missionaries to Finland and I were struggling to have any conversation at all wholly in Finnish. Compare that to our Swedish counterparts who were chatting away like they were born to it. I therefore know from experience that some graduate the MTC quite proficient - some not so much.